# Как подключить CoordinatorLayout вместе с ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, coordinator-layout

Как использовать CoordinatorLayout со списком?
Пробовал добавить ListView в итоге верхний AppBar не поднимается.

Но в инете видел много примеров где список работает. Как сделать не знаю.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/test"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView">
        </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Как подключить ListView?

---

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы добавили app:layout_behavior атрибут для ListView?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,Как подключить ListView?

Comment: У вас же в разметке нету ListView... Надо заменить NestedScrollView на него и добавить код из моего ответа. А лучше RecyclerView использовать - с ним проблем не будет

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, сорри не то. Вот сейчас тот код.

Comment: Не надо оборачивать ListView в NestedScrollView. Они конфлитктуют меж собой как любые вложенные скроллящиеся контейнеры.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, тут у меня и загвоздка. Если не ложить в NestedScrollView. то ListView скролить не будет.
А по другому listView не скролиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вам надо добавить вот эти [строки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30680195/3212712), кои помогут `ListView` получать события скрола от `Coordinatorlayout`. Без этих строк устаревший `ListView` не сможет их получать, в отличие от современной замены `ListView` - `RecyclerView`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}
```

Также, надо убрать `NestedScrollView`, оборачивающий `ListView` - в нём нет надобности и он может конфликтовать с `ListView`.

А атрибут `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` надо указывать для прямого скролящегося потомка `СoordinatorLayout`. Если `ListView` при этом, будет обёрнут в `SwipeRefreshLayout`, то этот атрибут должен быть именно у него, как прямого потомка `СoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: Все работает). Вы были правы. спс

RecyclerView я не использую потому что он слишком сложный и чтобы она заработала надо примерно 2 класса писать. Ну это вообще ужас. Легче ListView переделать

Comment: У меня к вам еще просьба одна. Почему когда ListView пролистываю вверх. То FAB появляется снизу. А после сверху? это БАГ?

Comment: Вот на картинке, видите. Она снизу. А потом сверху. Это Баг? или это можно исправить?

Comment: @xTIGRx, RecyclerView чуть сложнее, да. Но взамен вы получаете потрясающую гибкость и поддержку всех новых фич, анимаций и прочая. Оно того стоит.

Comment: @xTIGRx, про FAB не могу сказать. Такого не встречал. Могу лишь предположить, что это из-за ListView. В разметке всё верно указано. Так что баг. Попробуйте откатить либы на не самые последние и/или протестировать через NestedScrollView.